# Enviar objeto javascript al controlador y redireccionar página sin Ajax con jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typescript

Mi caso es el siguiente. En mi controlador tengo un ActionResult que recibe como parámetro un Dto y en el  antes de retornar la vista obtengo una lista que luego se lo envía al modelo para así solo usar dropdownlist y listar mi select.

Código del Controlador

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}

public ActionResult Datos(PersonaDto personaDto)
{
   personaModel.ListarTipoDocumento = persBl.listarTipoDoc();

   return View(adjuDocuModel);
}
```

Mi duda es la siguiente como puedo hacer para enviar un objeto javascript al controlador sin usar ajax con jquery, ya que solo necesito enviar el objeto y el actionResult se encarga de redireccionar a una nueva página

Objeto de ejemplo:

```
var Person = {
   Id: '5555',
   Nombre: 'nombres',
   Apellido: 'Apellidos'
}
```

Vista Index

```
@model demo.models....etc

---script---
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Person = {
        Id: '5555',
        Nombre: 'nombres',
        Apellido: 'Apellidos'
    }

    //----function : código que envía el objeto al controlador


});
---script---
```

Comment: Cual es el lenguaje de la vista ? html ? Quien es tú cliente ?, te diria de un formulario realizando una petición post corriente con HTML y un poco de Javascript con FormData y cúando llegue a tú metodo y termine el proceso haces un redirect, return Redirect("http://www.google.com");

Comment: Hola, si es html lo acabo de editar la vista index es mi cliente.

Comment: Puedes poner tu codigo del archivo .cshtml? es tu archivo html de la vista

Comment: mi vista no tiene ninguna etiqueta html solo la estructura del layout, ya que solo es una demo de prueba, pero con un resultado parecido a lo que necesito en mi proyecto. Al cargar la vista index envía el objeto al controlador o a la vista Datos

Comment: Pero tengo la posibilidad de agregar un formulario a la vista con javascript ?
$(document.body).append(form); porque sería necesario para hacer la petición sin "Ajax" como dices, esto es el motivo por el cúal es crucial si se puede añadir el elemento form al cuerpo de la página/vista 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053775/getting-error-form-submission-canceled-because-the-form-is-not-connected